# Polar Plot out of alignment

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

Trying to plot a polar plot with 5 variables for "theta" but the plot is out of alignment with the points. Here is what I have tried:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

r = np.arange(0, 2, 0.01)
theta = 2 * np.pi * r

theta = 'NH$_4$','TMA','TEA','TPA','TBA'
TZ2P = [6.76,6.63,6.81,7.06,7.10]
QZ4P = [3.56,3.62,3.79,3.89,3.95]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'})
ax.errorbar(theta, TZ2P, capsize=7, fmt="o", c="lightsteelblue",  mec='Black', label='PBE / TZ2P')
ax.errorbar(theta, QZ4P, capsize=7, fmt="o", c="darkseagreen",  mec='Black', label='PBE / QZ4P')
ax.set_rmax(7.5)
ax.set_rticks([0.5,  1.5,  2.5,  3.5,  4.5,  5.5,  6.5,  7.5])  # Less radial ticks
ax.set_rlabel_position(-18)  # Move radial labels away from plotted line
ax.grid(True)
ax.set_xticks(np.pi/180. * np.linspace(0, 360, 5, endpoint=False))

plt.legend(frameon=False)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to align the grid lines in the radial direction with the points, simply comment out:

```py
ax.set_xticks(np.pi/180.*np.linspace(0, 360, 5, endpoint=False))
```

With that `linspace`, you are forcing lines at angles 0, 72, 144, 216, and 288 degrees.

You can also change the `linspace` for a vector with the angles that you want for the grid lines.